# CreateWindowEx() Slow On Windows-7 (Sometimes)

Tags: performance, winapi, windows-7, windows-xp

I am having quite bad performance problems on Windows-7 (and probably Vista), with calls to CreateWindowEx().

Some of the windows I am creating are taking **much** longer in Windows-7 than XP. Times can be as high as 15-25 ms which is a lot when you need to create many. (Times on XP are consistently 0-2 ms.) **Why is this? and what can be done?**

All windows are created in the same thread. Some are built in window-classes some are my own. To me it seems that all windows with WS_POPUP [EDIT: and WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW] suffer from this delay, and all windows without it don't. (But the actual cause could of course be some other property.) This seems to apply for all my windows, except a RICHEDIT_CLASS control, which is the only one which inconsistently varies between 1-30 ms, but only on 7.
Thanks!

[EDIT: The app suffers most from a many ( ~300 ) tool-tips  created as the main window is created, using [gToolTip](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/Tool_Tip.aspx). I could delay tooltip creation until the window is shown but I have other "evil" windows, and I would still like to understand exactly what is happening]

**UPDATE:** My issue with tool-tips is greatly improved. The wrapper-class I used from CodeProject was not suitable [for being called 300 times, once for each control], as it creates a new window for each call. The trick is to create one tool-tip window (for each pop-up) and then only send a TTM_ADDTOOL-message to it for each control.

So performance is much improved, but a noticable lag still remains for the other windows...

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned `WS_POPUP`, it could have something to do with the [`CS_SAVEBITS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff729176%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) class style if you're creating the windows with `WS_VISIBLE` set.

> CS_SAVEBITS (0x0800)
>
> Saves, as a bitmap, the portion of the screen image obscured by a window of this class. ... This style increases the time required to display the window, because the system must first allocate memory to store the bitmap.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, but alas but none of the [evil] windows are created visible. Some have the CS_SAVEBITS and some do not... The only common properties that I have observed are WS_POPUP and WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW. See edit above...

Answer (score 1):

Turn off Aero if you want to dumb it down back to XP.  Its compositing feature that enables stuff like glass and live thumbnails does *not* come for free.

Comment: I am afraid that is not a solution. We cannot expect all our users to do that.

Comment: Yeah, users can be *so* unreasonable :)

Comment: As our app works fine on XP, I'd rather tell them download an XP-crack and uninstall Windows-7 :p

Comment: And anyway Aero IS off. So it is not a factor at all.